# How to tell GDB to look into include file c++ for debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, vscode-debugger

I want to debug my c++ program which uses a function from another `.cc` file.

I am using vscode in ubuntu.

a very simplified version of my code is here:

```
#include "tcp_utils.h"

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    
    // starting a socket connection with a client

    int sd; // server socket
    char req[250]; // received message

    while ((n = readline(sd,req,249)) != recv_nodata) { // readline is defined in tcp_utils.h
        // do something with req
    }
}
```

I compile and run the program without any error and it works correctly with this command:

```
g++ -g -pedantic -Wall -Werror -pthread -c -o tcp_utils.o tcp_utils.cc
g++ -g -pedantic -Wall -Werror -pthread -c -o cserv.o cserv.cc
g++ -g -pedantic -Wall -Werror -pthread -o cserv cserv.o tcp_utils.o
```

when I start vs code debugger it says:

> The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: g++-11 build active file' terminated with
> exit code -1.

in terminal:

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: g++-11 build active file 

Starting build...
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/g++-11 -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/shahriar/cpp/bbserver/cserv.cc -o /home/shahriar/cpp/bbserver/cserv
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: /tmp/ccsisDBl.o: in function `do_client(int)':
/home/shahriar/cpp/bbserver/cserv.cc:165: undefined reference to `readline(int, char*, unsigned long)'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: /tmp/ccsisDBl.o: in function `main':
/home/shahriar/cpp/bbserver/cserv.cc:390: undefined reference to `passivesocket(unsigned short, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

it says `readline` and `passivesocket` functions which are defined inside `tcp_utils.h` file are undefined.

how to tell gdb (or vscode) to look into `tcp_utils.h` file for debugging?

I also checked [why gdb cannot find source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888143/why-gdb-cannot-find-source-file) answer but i cannot figure it out.

Comment: The problem is unrelated to debugging. It's a *build* error. And you get it because by default when you build with the VSCode C++ plugin is to build the current file you have opened, not build and link all files in a "project". You need to create a `tasks.json` file to specify how you want to build your program. I also suggest you do some research about build-tools like `make` or meta-build tools like CMake, to help you with multi-file projects.

Comment: [This guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) should be helpful, please read it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm using a `Makefile` to compile and build the project. I copied the compile commands from my Makefile. So, I should specify include files inside `tasks.json`?

Comment: If you have a `Makefile` and want to run `make` when building, then you have to configure `tasks.json` to invoke `make` in the projects directory.